# Проблема при создании JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, jpa

Пытаюсь написать приложение, которое взаимодействует с БД MySQL (оная установлена и создана).

Для начала, у меня есть **pom.xml** с двумя зависимостями:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Есть xml-файл (**persistence.xml**), в котором описан конфиг Hibernate'а:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="org.hibernate.tutorial.jpa">

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/PersonManager"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="12345"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet" value="utf8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="utf8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <!-- use encache provider-->
            <!--<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"-->
            <!--value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>-->
            <!--<property name="hibernate.javax.cache.provider" value="org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider"/>-->
            <!--&lt;!&ndash;use second level cache&ndash;&gt;-->
            <!--<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>-->
            <!--&lt;!&ndash;use 3rd level cache&ndash;&gt;-->
            <!--<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>-->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Имеется ORM (**`Student.java`**):

```java
 import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Students")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "incrementor")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "clas")
    private String clas;

    // Setters

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setClas(String clas) {
        this.clas = clas;
    }


    // Getters

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getClas() {
        return clas;
    }
}
```

И теперь, есть точка входа (**`Main.java`**):

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String... main) {
        // Тут возникает эксепшн!
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("org.hibernate.tutorial.jpa");

        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setId(3); // В бд уже есть 2 записи
        student.setName("Albert");
        student.setClas("11-X");

        entityManager.persist(student);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }
}
```

Запускаю код и ловлю следующий стек-трейс:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.addConnections(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.<init>(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections$Builder.build(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'MSK' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:76)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'MSK' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:85)
    at com.mysql.cj.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:128)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.configureTimezone(NativeProtocol.java:2236)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.initServerSession(NativeProtocol.java:2260)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1314)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:963)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
    ... 33 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

В чём тут проблема?

Comment: Написано же "The server time zone value 'MSK' is unrecognized". [Установите правильный часовой пояс.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте зону времени одним из следующих способов (или всеми):

```
@PostConstruct
void init() {
   TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+3"));
}
```

или можно использовать свойство Hibernate:

```
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" value="UTC+3"/>
```

сервер конфигурация

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/PersonManager?serverTimezone=UTC%2B3&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false"/>
```

Comment: Я добавил то, что Вы посоветовали в конфиг. И теперь у меня такой стек-трейс: ```The server time zone value 'MSK' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support```

Comment: Да, я понял, у драйвера JDBC нет такой зоны времени.

Comment: если использовать ```UTC+3``` - то всё равно не помогает :(

Comment: Правда вы можете попробовать MSK вместо UTC+3, может это сработает

Comment: @SlandShow проблема не на стороне Java, проблема в конфигурации СУБД. Установите в настройках правильный часовой пояс и всё заработает.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Только вот вопрос: у меня ни UTC+3, ни MSK не работает. Какую же timezone мне нужно поставить?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Вообще у меня вот такое вот показывает...

```| system_time_zone | MSK    |```
```| time_zone        | SYSTEM |```

Comment: @SlandShow видимо по ссылке в моём комментарии вы переходить даже не пробовали. Либо `Europe/Moscow` либо `+03:00`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Спасибо Вам большое - помогло!